# Set background color for RecyclerView item depending on content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Short Description:
I'm displaying expected vs counted inventory in the *RecyclerView* items. The idea is to make the quantities RED if there's a difference b/n expected and counted items, and black otherwise. The result I got is that all items in all cards end up red.

My attempt:
I tried comparing the two quantities from *onBindViewHolder()* where most item specific things are written, but I didn't get the result.

```
public class PastInvDetailsAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PastInvDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Material> countedquantity;
PastInvDetailsActivity currentActivity;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView material_description;
    public TextView actualquantity;
    public TextView countedquantity;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        material_description = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_past_inv_details_material_desc);
        actualquantity = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_past_inv_details_current_no);
        countedquantity = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_past_inv_details_counted_no);
    }
}

public PastInvDetailsAdapter(ArrayList<Material> countedquantity, PastInvDetailsActivity currentActivity) {
    this.countedquantity = countedquantity;
    this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
}

@Override
public PastInvDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(currentActivity.getApplicationContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.past_inventory_details_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.material_description.setText(countedquantity.get(position).getMaterial() + " " +
            countedquantity.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.actualquantity.setText("Expected: " + countedquantity.get(position).getActualquantity());
    holder.countedquantity.setText("Counted: " + countedquantity.get(position).getQuantity());

    int actualInt = Integer.parseInt(countedquantity.get(position).getActualquantity());
    int expectedInt = Integer.parseInt(countedquantity.get(position).getQuantity());

    if (actualInt != expectedInt) {
        holder.countedquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.actualquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        holder.countedquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.actualquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return countedquantity.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the problem by any chance?

```
 if (actualInt != expectedInt) {
    holder.countedquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    holder.actualquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    holder.countedquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    holder.actualquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Change to:

```
if (actualInt != expectedInt) {
    holder.countedquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    holder.actualquantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    holder.countedquantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    holder.actualquantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: I'll be in my box of shame if anyone needs me.